# how to update the list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

When the user adds an item then display the list, the program will output the list without considering the user's added items It seems to me that the items aren't really added. I need your help guys. And..

- What is the use of **retract**? I just want to make sure my information
- Any criticism to improve this code is welcomed -if you ever figured out what the program meant to do-

`%00:33 du bist toll!
    :-dynamic item/1.`

```
item([coffee,milk,chocolate,apple,juice]).

menu:-
 nl, write("**SHOPPING LIST **"),nl,
 write('d - Display all items.'), nl,
 write('a - Add an item to the list.'), nl,
 write('e - Exit.'),
 write('-------------------------------'), nl,
 write('Enter your choice: '),
 read(X), check(X),(X=e;menu).

check(a):-
    nl,
 write('Enter the item you want to add to the shopping list'), nl,

 %adding to list operations
  read(I),
    item(L),not(member(I,L)),
    retract(item(L)),
    assert(item([I|L])),
  write('The item has been added').

check(d):-
    nl,
    item(L),
 displayL(L).

displayL([]).
displayL([X|Y]):- write(X),nl, displayL(Y).


check(e):-.
```

Comment: `check(e):-.` is a syntax error. Defining `menu` to be a recursive call on every new menu choice that isn't an exit is not a good practice as you continue to use more stack as the program progresses. See the online documentation for [`retract/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=retract/1).

Comment: items *are* added, at beginning.